# Formula for the first derivative of $\frac{x^n}{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had a homework problem to calculate the derivative of $$\frac{x}{e^x}$$ which I did, successfully, but then I figured there would be a more general formula for the derivative of $\frac{x^n}{e^x}$, considering how easy it was to find this derivative. So I calculated a couple more derivatives with values of $n$ increasing by one i.e. $x^2, x^3 \ldots$ and found the following formula:

$$f^{'}(x) = \frac{x^{n-1}(n-x)}{e^x}$$

This works for higher powers of $x$ too. For example, the derivative of $\frac{x^2}{e^x}$ is

$$\begin{align}
&f^{'}(x) = \frac{x^{n-1}(n-x)}{e^x} \\
&f^{'}(x) = \frac{x^{2-1}(2-x)}{e^x} \\
&f^{'}(x) = \frac{x(2-x)}{e^x}
\end{align}$$

and if [you check through W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20x%5E2/e%5Ex), it is correct. To verify that this is formula is correct, I took an arbitrary $n$.

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
f^{'}(x) &= \frac{x^{n}}{e^x} \\
&= \frac{nx^{n-1}e^x - x^ne^x}{(e^x)^2} \\
&= \frac{x^{n-1}e^x (n - x)}{e^{2x}} \\
&= \frac{x^{n-1}\cancel{e^x} (n-x)}{\cancel{e^{2x}}} \\
&= \frac{x^{n-1}(n-x)}{e^x} \\
\end{align}

And there you have it. Is this a valid way to show the derivation of the formula? Also, is the formula correct?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: *Hint*: I think you may have to re-phrase the question: *"Find the **first** derivative of $x^n/e^x$..."*

Comment: @AndreaL. I'm looking to find a general formula for the $n^th$ derivative of the that function so isn't my title correct?

Comment: Sorry, I may have sound rude; but since I want you to "see" the basic concepts at work rather than giving just the result, maybe this tip would help. You derived **once** a function whose exponent is related to $n$, and as you shown, no matter how it can be derived, the factor $e^x$ simplifies (the denominator is constant). But the numerator now is the function $nx^{n-1}-x^n$, which is only the **first** derivation of the quotient. You have to carry on deriving $n$ times the numerator, which will lead to a pattern...

Comment: I think you are right about changing the title of the question. I'm not asking for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{x^n}{e^x}$ but my intention was to find a formula for $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{x^a}{e^x}$ where $a$ is any positive number greater than 0. So, if you put $a=2$ then the formula I provided works and I wanted someone to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Apply [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) to the product $x^n e^{-x}.$

Comment: I have updated the question, I believe it was unclear before. I am not looking for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $x^n e^{-x}$ but rather, I'm looking for the first derivative of $x^{a}*e^{-x}$ where $a$ is any positive greater than zero.